# How does max work for a mixed type list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I was playing around with the following:

```
>>> l = [1, 2.0, 'a', 'aaz', '9', 'ab', 999999]
>>> max(l)
'ab'
```

I wasn't expecting this at first, but then I figured it has something to do with some order or precedence of types.  If this is correct, what is the order and what is the reasoning?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only works in Python2. The incompatible types are ordered by the name of the type "str" > "int"

In Python3, you are no longer allowed to compare `str` and `int`

Comment: I hadn't thought to search for questions regarding comparing (`>`) different types.  Weird that this would be included in python2.  Anyway, thank you.